# how to constraint data to keep right data in soft delete laravel

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

I intend to use soft delete for my laravel project and i wonder how to assure data alway right ?

My thought is like this: to create soft delete i have to create delete_at column to use soft delete. But what will happen if i insert a record exactly same the 'deleted' record (except value of delete_at column ) ?

If delete_at isn't in primary key then i cannot add new record right ? But what if i put delete_at into primary key ? I think it's a bad idea.

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: deleted_at is a timestamp, why would even make it a primary key? by default, a new record will be created - assuming that fields are not set as unique in the SQL table.

Comment: why not to use incremented id? even though in your model you will have to specify a primary key so it consider as a unique row. making a time stamp as a primary key is not insure of uniqueness and as you know you primary key cannot have null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of soft deletes, one uses almost always auto-incremented integer primary keys to avoid constraint violations caused by reinsertion.